# SSH connection getting closed automatically after a sudo command

Tags: ssh, redhat, sudo

I have two servers running the same version of RedHat 6.4, however one of them behaves differently when I run remote `sudo` commands through SSH on it. On **server1**, the connection is automatically closed after a **successful** `sudo` command, but on **server3**, the connection is kept open and further commands can be run.

Note that for these tests the `sudo` user had the `NOPASSWD` flag so no prompt is asked. As far as I know, all configurations on these servers are the same (they were cloned).

I tested using this:

```
ssh -vvv user@server1 << EOF
sudo ls -l /home/
ls -l /home/
pwd
EOF
```

If I run this on server1 I get a single file listing.

```
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 1621
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user       user       4096 Apr 26  2013 user
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
```

Running without the sudo command on the same server I get my two file listing and the pwd result

```
ssh -vvv user@server1 << EOF
ls -l /home/
ls -l /home/
pwd
EOF
```

Result:

```
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 1605
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user       user       4096 Apr 26  2013 user
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user       user       4096 Apr 26  2013 user
/home/user
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
```

However, running the script with the sudo command on server3 I get the result of all 3 commands like the previous test. I compared the output of the ssh -vvv logs from both servers (1 and 3) and everything seems the same except for a debug line in a different order when the connection is closed (see client_input... line).

server1 (same with or without `sudo`)

```
[command results]
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
```

server3

```
[command results]
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
```

I would like to know how to fix server1 so that the connection isn't automatically closed so that my script can execute completely when including `sudo` commands.

Some options I already checked:

- SE Linux is disabled
- The `passwd` file is properly configured with the `/bin/bash` shell
- errexit is off (command is successful anyway)
- `sudoers` and `sshd_config` configuration is the same between the two servers

The only difference between the servers I see is that the buggy server1 is an older generation of server, it's a ProLiant DL380 G7 compared to a G8 for server3. Other servers I've tried and that are working are also G8 (I only have one G7 to try on). I don't see how the hardware can cause that type of issue.

Comment: Check the system logs.

Comment: Any log in particular? the `ssh -vvv` debug doesn't show anything. The sudo logs shows the command being executed. We haven't seen anything in the other logs that hint at anything.

Comment: The obvious one is `/var/log/cron`. Then there's `/var/log/messages` but probably that won't have much.

Comment: And you're also so many years behind on updates that it's quite possibly a bug that was fixed in an update that you haven't installed.

Comment: Nothing in the logs. The thing is that both servers have the same version of Linux (RHEL 6.4) with the same patches  since they are cloned, so in theory they should behave the same way.